# Import a word from a specific word document into a specific excel document

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to import a specific table from a specific microsoft word document into a certain excel sheet.

The table is in a specific word document, and then I'm trying to paste it in the excel cell range E8:N21 of the correct excel sheet.

I've adapted this code below but continually get issues:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdHuddle) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If
With .tables(TableNo)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Right now, it also asks to import the correct word document, but that isn't necessary as it will always pull the table from the same word document from a specific location

Answer (score 0):

Below is code that does what you request, and an animated gif showing it being run.  All you need to do is replace fName with the complete path to your Word doc, and change the row & column start position to iCol=5, iRow=9 (E9) in the for loops.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim fName As String

'============= PLACE YOUR WORD DOCUMENT PATH HERE =================
fName = "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Desktop\Test.docx"

Set wdDoc = GetObject(fName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If
With .tables(TableNo)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]